# np.savetxt changes the result

Tags: python, python-2.7

Here is the result after some calculations: -2.01115250223. Python changes it as -2.240785557768. I get the first result with print command and the second one with the code which is given below

```
np.savetxt('result.txt',output0,fmt='%10.3e',delimiter=' ')
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: can you show us the code before that, i.e. how you got `output0`?

Comment: 'Output0' should be a 1D or 2D like array, not a float.

Comment: `output0 = []
out0 = [A,T]
    output0.append(out0)`

Comment: create minimal working code which we could run and see problem.